Extract video bitrate/FFMPEG
ffprobe -i /test_b200.webm -v quiet -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1

I use this command to get the video bitrate. The difficulty is that it works with mp4.
Tried to get it from the format webm, unsuccessfully...
N/A

Is it possible with the help of FFMPEG, extract video bitrate regardless of extension? Or did I convert it incorrectly in webm?
Second question, is it possible to determine by bitrate?
Will it be an exact value or an approximate one?

The WebM file is likely encoded (with VP8 or VP9) using a Variable bitrate (VBR), which means it basically doesn't have a constant bit rate which can be seen in the metadata since it's variable throughout the file (see Bitrate Modes in Detail).
The workaround would be to estimate/calculate the average bitrate across the file based on a calculation using the total file size and the duration of the video (using the formula of filesize * 8 / duration, which is basically filesize in bytes * 8 (to get the filesize in bits) / duration (in seconds) ) which will give you an average number of bits per second in the video.

I convert video files into many qualities. I focus on the frame height of the original video. I also expect to focus on the bitrate. Since the frame height can be large, and the quality itself leaves much to be desired...
Perhaps you can recommend a module for Paytan? Which will definitely get the bitrate from any file?

I can't, and it'd most certainly be out of the scope of this question. The first thing to take into mind is - as I wrote - a VBR encoding file will not have a real "the bitrate", it's variable
